# Eclipse combination opposite to Ctr+Z

Tags: eclipse

I really need Eclipse combination opposite to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. When we navigate back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> sometimes we need to go further. How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shortcut to do the opposite of <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> :-)

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users the key bindings are:

**Undo:** <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

**Redo:** <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

You can change these binding by going to:

Eclipse > Preferences > General > Keys

Answer (score 0):

undo: ctrl + Z

Redo: shift + ctrl + Z

it works ........... try this